# Android: User ordering items a Grid (or other component)

Tags: android, gridview, gallery

I'd like to be able to display a set of image thumbnails and allow the user to long-press, then drag the image to change the order.  I've been looking at the events, and I think there's a way to do this, but it will be painful to code well.  Just wondering if there's a component out there that does it.

The "Gallery" component is also an option.